# How to hide and show custom filter form on a drupal view

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, drupal-7, drupal-views

I'm new to Drupal and I'm trying to create a view with many filter options, 
because it has a lot of filter fields I want them to be hidden and only show the filter fields the user decides he wants to see at a given time.

I couldnit find a module to get the said affect so i tried to use panels and add my own html and jQuery custom code:

**HTML**

```
<input type="button" id="filter-selection-toggle-button" value="show filters"/>
<div id="my-filter-selection">
    <input type="checkbox"  value="edit-field-1">field 1</input><br/>
    <input type="checkbox"  value="edit-field-2">field 2</input><br/>
    <input type="checkbox"  value="edit-field-3">field 3</input><br/>
    <input type="checkbox"  value="edit-field-4">field 4</input><br/>
    <input type="checkbox"  value="edit-field-5">Dimention</input><br/>
    <input type="button" id="filter-button" value="filters button"/>
</div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        // We define a function that takes one parameter named $.
        (function ($) {
            $(document).ready(function()
            {
                var showCheckedFilters=function(event)
                {
                    var x=$("input:checkbox:checked");
                    var y=$("input:checkbox:not(:checked)");
                    var checkedFilters="";//array of checked filters
                    var unCheckedFilters="";//array of checked filters
                    var toggleSpeed=event.data.toggleSpeed;

                    for (var i=0;i<x.length;i++)
                    {
                        checkedFilters=checkedFilters+"#"+$(x).eq(i).val()+","; 
                    }

                    for (var i=0;i<y.length;i++)
                    {
                        unCheckedFilters=unCheckedFilters+"#"+$(y).eq(i).val()+","; 
                    }


                    if (checkedFilters!="") 
                    {
                            // remove comma
```

checkedFilters=checkedFilters.substring(0,checkedFilters.length-1);
                                $(checkedFilters+",.view-filters").show(toggleSpeed);
                        }
                        else    // all are unchecked
                        {
                                $(".view-filters").hide(toggleSpeed);
                        }

```
                    if (unCheckedFilters!="") 
                    {
                            // remove comma
                            unCheckedFilters=unCheckedFilters.substring(0,unCheckedFilters.length-1);
                            $(unCheckedFilters).hide(toggleSpeed);
                    }
                };

            // Now use jQuery with the $ shortcut again like you normally would

            $("#my-filter-selection,.view-filters").hide();
            //showCheckedFilters();//hide nondefault filters
            $("#filter-selection-toggle-button").click(function(){$("#my-filter-selection").toggle(500);});
            $("#filter-button").click({toggleSpeed:500},showCheckedFilters);
            //$("#edit-submit-items-in-market").click({toggleSpeed:0},showCheckedFilters);

           //to do on every reload of the filters
           $(document).ajaxComplete({toggleSpeed:0},showCheckedFilters);
        });
        // Here we immediately call the function with jQuery as the parameter.
        }(jQuery));
    </script>
```

All seems to work fine up until the drupal filter is actually used, apparently drupal reloads the filter fields using ajax and not only the content, at which point all the filters appear again.

In order to avoid this I tried capturing the ajax call using

```
$(document).ajaxComplete({toggleSpeed:0},showCheckedFilters);
```

or adding my own call to the drupal submit button:

```
$("#edit-submit-items-in-market").click({toggleSpeed:0},showCheckedFilters);
```

both to no avail.

So:

1. is there a way to make sure the unchecked filters stay hidden?
2. is there a better solution than adding the above html piece all together?

(note I'm not versed in the drupal api so sending me to change tpl files or creating a custom module is not a very good option).

Example:

filtered:

[image]

unfiltered (after pressing apply):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Can you be more specific about what you want to filter?

Anyhow, I think you should check this module - https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_conditional

You can also cancel ajax on the advance settings in the Drupal view

Comment: the webform module is for adding filed dependency while creating content. im trying to show or hide exposed filter fields in a view. i added an image for better understanding. as for removing ajax - its not a very user friendlly option and i prefer to use that as a last resort.

Comment: Well, If you stick with ajax, I would consider using Angular and its filtering options.
That might help you - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XYYi2x19ZTg
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fkSXAnUFC4Y

Comment: the filtering is done through drupal views i am not going to change that, that would be hacking into the module and im far from familiar with drupal api enpugh to attempt that, i just what to do simple html style manipulation

Comment: You can export the view as an xml, using views data export https://www.drupal.org/project/views_data_export
Then, you can use a javascript framework to fetch the data and filter it.
There might also be a module that will export the data as a json

Comment: i need to show the data on the site not to export it, the whole point is to make the site prettier for the users

Comment: If you want the whole data to be appended and loaded only from the view, you can't use Ajax in order to filter your data. In that case, use simple JavaScript or Jquery in order to hide and view your data according to the options you want. Make sure you load your script after the data is loaded

Comment: i think you miss inturpurtt my intention i dont manipulate the data - i leave that to the view (it does it fine) i just dont want the exposed filters to be present all the time (they take like half a page) so i devised a method to hide them and only show the filter fields when requested (see images above), i dont manipulate the data itself in any way nor do i intend to

Comment: According to what you're saying, the view is loading all the data, not only the filters (correct me if I'm wrong) - That's what views  should do anyway.
If you want to filter the data or show/hide the filters that has already been loaded, you should cancel Ajax and stick to the jQuery that shows and hides the filters.
You're only alternative, is that one that I've mentioned before - export the data to a different file (such as xml or Json) and load the data from there using Ajax or any front-end frame work.

Comment: i still think you dont understand - the view loads the data correctlly, the view also filters the data using exposed filter fields (both work perfectlly) all i want is for the user to choose which elements he wants to filter by and then i present only those fields (hiding the others using jquary) problem is it reloads the presentation layer of the filters when hitting apply and not only the data - thats what i need to intercept and hide the fields again (until such time that the user chooses to show them) or i dont understan yout answer (allso possible)

Comment: Ok, I get you now. What about canceling the filtering options of the view? Why not considering letting the view load everything and let the filtering all to be done by the user?

Comment: im using exposed filters (second image) its just there are alot of those which is why i try to hide them (its like letting the user select the exposed filters at any given time - like in the first image) the problem is with the reloading of the exposed filter fields (like if i have a model field and a price field and the user  wants only one to show he chooses it and the other one is gone, now if he sets a price and press apply the data is filtered by the view but instead of just reloading the table it also shows both exposed filter fields again - model and price)

Comment: I understand the problem now and looking at your code.
First thing I notice is that checkedFilters and unCheckedFilters aren't define as arrays, yet as a strings - did you mean to do that?

Comment: yep cause jquary recieve text string as a selector- it work fine, i just cant seem to get $(document).ajaxComplete({toggleSpeed:0},showCheckedFilters); to intercept reloading of the exposed filter fields div

Comment: try any of the events mentioned here - http://api.jquery.com/Ajax_Events/

in the meanwhile, I'll try to see if there's anything wrong with your code